# I have a list of 'illegal characters' and another list of strings. I want to replace any illegal characters in the list of strings with an underscore

Tags: python, python-3.x

How could I remove all the illegal characters from each string in the `my_titles` list and replace them with an underscore?

Here is my code:

```
illegal_chars=['?',':','>','<','|']
my_titles=['Memoirs | 2018','>Example<','May: the 15th']
```

Would I have to use a nested for loop or is there an easier/cleaner way to do it? Thank you!

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Alright! Thank you! Should I edit my post or leave it as is for now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in illegal_chars:
    my_titles=[k.replace(i, '_') for k in my_titles]

>>> print(my_titles)
['Memoirs _ 2018', '_Example_', 'May_ the 15th']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
illegal_chars=['?',':','>','<','|']
my_titles=['Memoirs | 2018','>Example<','May: the 15th']
new_titles = []
for i in my_titles:
    for j in illegal_chars:
        if j in i:
            i = i.replace(j,'_')
            new_titles.append(i)

print(new_titles)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
illegal_chars=['?',':','>','<','|']
my_titles=['Memoirs | 2018','>Example<','May: the 15th']

for i in range(len(my_titles)):
   for char in illegal_chars:
      if char in my_titles[i]:
         my_titles[i] = my_titles[i].replace(char, "_")
```